# Can I obsolete a specific usage of an attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a custom attribute currently defined thus:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute {}
```

I now want to obsolete the usage on an interface -  leaving just Class usage. I would prefer not to just delete that usage  -  because I want to generate a warning/advice to any existing usages on interfaces. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can. You are limited to deleting it or making a v2 version of your class and obsoleting this entire class.

Comment: Mark the attribute obsolete, throw on incorrect usage, create a new one.  Pull it fast like a band-aid. It'll only hurt for a little bit.

Comment: I realised I could do that  -  but that would necessitate a different name (or namespace) for the attribute.  I know the attribute is used extensively on classes, but likely not much on interfaces  -  so I am reluctant to change the name for the common usage.  Worst-case I'll just delete the Interface usage and add a documentary comment.

Comment: I'll leave my answer here then, not much more to be said about it really as only you can decide what your best option is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that. You have 2 options that I can think of:

1. Delete the reference to `Interface` and potentially break any code that uses it.

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
   public class MyAttribute : Attribute {}
   ```
2. Make a v2 version of the attribute and make the original one obsolete entirely

   ```
   [Obsolete("Use MyNewAttribute instead")]
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Interface)]
   public class MyAttribute : Attribute {}

   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
   public class MyNewAttribute : Attribute {}
   ```

I prefer option 2, it's much cleaner and satisfies the ["O"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).